# jQuery insertAfter() making duplicate elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok so I'm using the following:

```
var recevingFolderID = $(this).attr("data-folderid");
var recevingFolderUl = $("[data-folderid='" + recevingFolderID + "']").next();

var folderLiToMove = $("[data-folderid='" + currentDraggedFolderID + "']");
var folderToMoveUl = folderLiToMove.next();
folderLiToMove.appendTo(recevingFolderUl);
folderToMoveUl.insertAfter(folderLiToMove);
```

The whole idea is that it is suppose to emulate a folder/ file structure where a folder is shown using an `li` and then underneath it the `ul` element is the contents of that given folder.

Now my problem is when I use `folderToMoveUl.insertAfter(folderLiToMove);` as shown in the example above, `insertAfter()` makes two `ul` elements when I use it. But if I were to use `folderToMoveUl.insertAfter("main");` it works fine where only one `ul` element is placed.

Now these `ul` elements are the same.

I would love to include a jsFiddle or CodePen but I can't seem to replicate the issue, I've tried to think what may be different but still no luck.

Like I said, I tried to replicate the problem I'm having in CodePen here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEeVJW but it works just fine, basically on my end if you were to drag Folder 2 over Folder 1, Folder 2 would get put inside of Folder 1 and the `ul` under Folder 2 along with it, but on my end the contents of Folder 2's `ul` get moved twice and I'm not sure why?

Comment: Try copying and pasting the code https://www.diffchecker.com/ to see if there is a difference you're not seeing.

Comment: I have and its all the same :( It must be something else in my JS code conflicting but I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: Are you able to post the entirety of your JS file here?

Comment: Arhh it turns out it was the `helper: "clone"` option on jQuery draggable on the folder `li` arhhh